# FFMPEG Stream series of pictures over network

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I would like to generate video frames on one computer and stream them to another computer to be manipulated and displayed.  I want to do this programatically, because the source images are generated from a 3rd party c++ library and on the receiving end I want to manipulate the images before displaying them.  I have been pulling my hair out trying FFMPEG.  I got the encoding example to work, but am not sure what to do after that.  I have just about googled everything i could think of but cannot figure out which FFMPEG library/function to call once I have a stuffed AVPacket.  It seems that I need to use either the AVIO or AVFormat or the muxer but it is not clear how to initialize and get them working.  I would appreciate any help you could offer.

To provide some context I have the example 'decoding_encoding.c' which is provided with ffmpeg working.  Here is the spot that I am struggling with:

```
        /* encode the image */
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (got_output) {
            printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);

            //
            // instead of writing to a file, i want to stream to a network
            // What do I need to do with pkt to do that?
            //
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
```

Most documentation (and the Dranger tutorial) focus on reading and writing files.  I do not need to use a file.  I want to stream video over a network.  It seems like I need AVFormat and AVio but I jsut can't figure out how they fit together.

Comment: Start with the dranger tutorial http://dranger.com/ffmpeg. After that if your still having problems, point the the specific step that is not working.

Comment: @szatmary, I figured it out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The key was to use avio_open2() to open the socket connection and then pass the data and size fields of pkt to avio_write().  He is an example working program (derived from decode_encode.c in the doc/examples directory of ffmpeg):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
/*
* Copyright (c) 2001 Fabrice Bellard
*
* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
* of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
* in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
* to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
* copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
* furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
* all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*
* THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
* IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
* THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
* OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
* THE SOFTWARE.
*/

/**
* @file
* libavcodec API use example.
*
* @example decoding_encoding.c
* Note that libavcodec only handles codecs (mpeg, mpeg4, etc...),
* not file formats (avi, vob, mp4, mov, mkv, mxf, flv, mpegts, mpegps, etc...). See library 'libavformat' for the
* format handling
*/

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <winsock.h>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
#include <libavformat\avio.h>
#include <libavformat\avformat.h>
}

#define INBUF_SIZE 4096
#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096


static void video_encode_example(const char *filename, AVCodecID codec_id)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
    errno_t err;
    int errval;
    printf("Encode video file %s\n", filename);

    /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 4000000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 1024;
    c->height = 768;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base.den = 25;
    c->time_base.num = 1;
    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
    * check frame pict_type before passing frame
    * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
    * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
    * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
    */
    c->gop_size = 12;
    c->max_b_frames = 0;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
    {
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
    }

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    AVFormatContext* format =  avformat_alloc_context();
    AVDictionary *options = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&options, "pkt_size", "1300", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "buffer_size", "65535", 0);
    AVIOContext * server = NULL;
    avio_open2(&server, "udp://192.168.0.13:5555", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, &options);

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;

    /* the image can be allocated by any means and av_image_alloc() is
    * just the most convenient way if av_malloc() is to be used */
    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height,
        c->pix_fmt, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Cycle through the test pattern for 1 hour
    for (int j = 0; j < 3600; j++)
    {
        /* encode 1 second of video */
        for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {

            Sleep(40);
            av_init_packet(&pkt);
            pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
            pkt.size = 1300;

            fflush(stdout);
            /* prepare a dummy image */
            /* Y */
            for (y = 0; y < c->height; y++) {
                for (x = 0; x < c->width; x++) {
                    frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
                }
            }

            /* Cb and Cr */
            for (y = 0; y < c->height / 2; y++) {
                for (x = 0; x < c->width / 2; x++) {
                    frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                    frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
                }
            }

            frame->pts = i+j*25;

            /* encode the image */
            ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            if (got_output) {
                printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
                //fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
                avio_write(server, pkt.data, pkt.size);
                av_free_packet(&pkt);
            }
        }
    }

    /* get the delayed frames */
    for (got_output = 1; got_output; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (got_output) {
            printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
            avio_write(server, pkt.data, pkt.size);
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
    }
    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *output_type;

    /* register all the codecs */
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    video_encode_example("test.h264", AV_CODEC_ID_H264);

    return 0;
}
```